# Facebook Api Graph error when trying to return threads of a Page

Tags: javascript, facebook

I ve been using this end point :

{page-id}/threads

and it returns the following:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#100) Tried accessing nonexisting field (threads) on node type (Business)",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 100,
    "fbtrace_id": "EdclPzbf+Aw"
  }
}
```

Comment: Quote docs: _“This endpoint is only accessible for users that are developers of the app making the request. **Pages should use the Conversation object.**”_

Comment: I ended up using "me/conversations" with the Page Access Token